# Conditionally Fill NA Values in R with String

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame in R that has x and y values. There are NA values in x I would like to fill with specific strings dependent upon the y values.

Example data frame:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = c("Canada", "United States", NA, NA, NA), 
        y = c("CAN", "USA", "TWN", "TWN", "ARG"))
```

Expected result:

```
df2 = data.frame(x = c("Canada", "United States", "Taiwan", "Taiwan", NA), 
        y = c("CAN", "USA", "TWN", "TWN", "ARG"))
```

I have tried

```
df2 <- df1 %>% transform(df1, x = ifelse(y == "TWN", "Taiwan", x))
```

but this removes all values of x and y for all other observations not containing "TWN". Most of the other examples I've found on here are replacing all NA values and I can't seem to figure out how to do it conditionally upon strings in another column. This will need to be done with very large data frames so efficiency is ideal.

Comment: Change `transform` to `mutate` i.e. `df1 %>% mutate(x = ifelse(as.character(y) == "TWN", "Taiwan", as.character(x)))`  If there are multiple elements, use a key/val dataset and join

Comment: I don't like the idea of hard coding that `TWN` maps to `Taiwan`.  I think you should at least have some mapping data frames which contains this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach here would be to maintain a data frame which has all the keys and replacements which you intend to use should a full country name be missing:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x=c("Canada", "United States", NA, NA, NA), 
                  y=c("CAN", "USA", "TWN", "TWN", "ARG"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(y=c("TWN", "ARG"), value=c("Taiwan", "Argentina"),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

result <- merge(df1, df2, by="y", all=TRUE)
result$x <- ifelse(is.na(result$x), result$value, result$x)
result <- result[, c("y", "x")]
result

    y             x
1 ARG     Argentina
2 CAN        Canada
3 TWN        Taiwan
4 TWN        Taiwan
5 USA United States
```

Comment: This is a great idea and something I would not have considered. Thank you for the recommendation, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to augment the levels of the factor column before you use "[" with logical indexing for the joint condion of 'x' being NA and 'y' being TWN.

```
> levels(df1$x) <- c(levels(df1$x), 'Taiwan')
> df1[is.na(df1$x) & df1$y=='TWN', 'x'] <- 'Taiwan'
> df1
              x   y
1        Canada CAN
2 United States USA
3        Taiwan TWN
4        Taiwan TWN
5          <NA> ARG
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to use data.table library in R

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)

df1[y=="TWN",x:="TAIWAN"]
```

That should work like a pro.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a lookUpTable (`named character`) for those problems.

```
lookUpTable = c("Canada", "United States", "Taiwan", "Argentina")
names(lookUpTable) = c("CAN", "USA", "TWN", "ARG")

#     CAN             USA             TWN             ARG 
#"Canada" "United States"        "Taiwan"     "Argentina" 

df1$x <- lookUpTable[df1$y]

#              x   y
#1 United States CAN
#2     Argentina USA
#3        Taiwan TWN
#4        Taiwan TWN
#5        Canada ARG
```

---

data:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = c("Canada", "United States", NA, NA, NA), 
                 y = c("CAN", "USA", "TWN", "TWN", "ARG"))
```